# Remap input event in all contexts

Tags: events

I'm currently trying to implement a virtual keyboard. For this to work I need to remap input events in all contexts.

I'm aware of the variables `function-key-map` and it's siblings, as well as input methods. However, they all seem to be applied to a new key sequences, but not in the middle of a key sequence.

What I need is a way to convert some mouse events into key events. And this should work both at the beginning of a key sequence as well as in the middle of one.

Concretely, if the user clicks on my virtual key for <kbd>2</kbd>, I want the digit `2` to be insert. However, if the user has typed <kbd>C-x</kbd> (either on a real keyboard or in my virtual keyboard) and click <kbd>2</kbd> on the virtual keyboard, I want the window to split (like <kbd>C-x 2</kbd> normally do).

All suggestions on how to precede are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

`function-key-map` and `input-decode-map` definitely apply in the middle of a key-sequence as well.